# sequelize many-to-many deep and nested association

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, polymorphic-associations

For context, I am new to sequelize, and I have googled extensively to find this before reaching out to the community.  I would be grateful for any help :)

I have 3 models to build a "family unit" that basically look like code below (dialect is mysql fyi).   What I desire is to make a call through the user table to get a data model that looks like this:

```
User => { Object of User }
     => id
     => firstName
     => lastName
     => email
     => active
     => families => [ Array of Family ]
                 => id
                 => name
                 => crew => [ Array of Users ]
                         => id
                         => firstName
                         => lastName
                         => email
                         => active
```

This is the code I'm using to try and accomplish this and getting close but no users on the through table coming back.

```
User.findOne({
      where: { id: 'my-guid-info'},
      include: {
        all: true,
        nested: true,
        through: {
          model: "Member",
        },
      },
    });
```

And here is the model code:

```
Family.init(
{
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: true,
    },
  },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, required: true },
},
{
  sequelize,
  modelName: "Family",
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
});

User.init(
{
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: true,
    },
  },
  active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true },
  firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
  lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true,
      notNull: true,
    },
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: { exclude: ["hash", "salt"] },
  },
});

Member.init(
{
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: true,
    },
  },
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    references: { model: "User", key: "id" },
  },
  familyId: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    references: { model: "Family", key: "id" },
  },
  relationship: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM("child", "parent", "primary"),
  },
},
{
  sequelize,
  modelName: "Member",
  timestamps: true,
});
```

I also have these associations setup on each model respectively.

```
User.associate = (models) => {
  User.belongsToMany(models.Family, {
    as: "families",
    through: {
      model: models.Member,
    },
    foreignKey: "userId",
    otherKey: "familyId",
  });
};

Family.associate = (models) => {
  Family.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    as: "crew",
    otherKey: "userId",
    attributes: {
      exclude: ["hash", "salt"],
    },
    through: { model: models.Member },
  });
};

Member.associate = (models) => {
  Member.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "userId" });
  Member.belongsTo(models.Family, { foreignKey: "familyId" });
};
```

Any direction, would be really appreciated, as I feel like I have tried all the elements of the relevant documentation, and several stackoverflow threads.